# CSS How to make a background not overlap with the navbar

Tags: css

The background image is partly snuggled under the navbar, which creates an awkward amount of space between the background and the rest of the site.

I tried to fix it with margin, but this only seemed to add space between the nav bar and the top of the background

https://jsitor.com/y8DJh9GIeu

Comment: It adds space because the image is right below the navbar and was never under the navbar. If there is space left under the image, set the height of the image to 100vh and remove background-size of the image

Answer (score 0):

The background image isnt underneath the navbar, that's why you get the extra "lip" underneath. You either need to make the background image 100vh minus the height of the nav bar, or absolute position the navbar on top of it.